# Vim from source with Python2.7

Tags: 16.04, python, compiling, vim, configure

I installed vim80 from GitHub with the configuration settings

```
--with-features=huge

--enable-multibyte

--enable-pythoninterp=yes

--with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/config.c

--enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr
```

and

```
make VIMRUNTIMEDIR=/usr/share/vim/vim80
```

Where vim is located. Yet when I execute

```
vim --version
```

I get `-python` aka that python is not implemented. I got all of the prerequisite libraries from

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libgnome2-dev libgnomeui-dev \
libgtk2.0-dev libatk1.0-dev libbonoboui2-dev \
libcairo2-dev libx11-dev libxpm-dev libxt-dev python-dev \
python3-dev ruby-dev lua5.1 lua5.1-dev libperl-dev git
```

and I removed all installed packages with "vim" in the name as well as vim itself. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The correct config dirs (on my 16.04.2 system) appear to be `-with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu/` for python2 and `--with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu/` for python3

Comment: I've used both of those config-dirs before and tried just now, still doesn't work. It said that the link to config.c in the dir was linked or something like that, no errors but it still doesn't work with any python version. I tried uninstalling it with dpkg -r vim and it gave me an "Package vim-nox which provides vim is not configured yet". Any ideas?

Comment: I ran vim.nox and executed "echo has('python3')" and it returned a "1"! But when I execute "vim" I get version 8.0.579 which doesn't have python. and in /usr/bin/vim I got vim 8.0.582 which doesn't have python either. I executed "echo $VIMRUNTIME in the 3 vim windows and one, without python, points to "/usr/local/share/vim" where no vim folder is and the other two to "/usr/share/vim/vim80/". So I got 2 different versions of vim pointing to the same runtime dir. Any fix?